# Web crawling problem: Can't delete \n characters

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using python right now to crawl data from a website. Things worked well until I found out that I just can't merge all the processed line at once.
Here's my buggy code: (I'm using scrapy for crawling)

```
rep = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[{:d}]'.format(i)).get()
rep = rep.replace('<div class="d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3">','')
rep = rep.replace('<div class="font-weight-bold">','')
rep = rep.replace('<span>','')
rep = rep.replace('</span>','')
rep = rep.replace('</div></div>',',')
rep = rep.replace('</div>','":')
rep = rep.replace('<div>','"')
rep.join(rep.split('\n'))
```

Raw input for that code:

```
<div class="search-result py-4 px-0 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 mx-auto mt-4"><div class="font-weight-bold mb-3 px-3">Candidate number : <span class="student-id text-dc3545">33000001</span></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3"><div>Math</div><div class="font-weight-bold">6.40</div></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3"><div>Literature</div><div class="font-weight-bold">4.50</div></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3"><div>History</div><div class="font-weight-bold">6.50</div></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3"><div>Geography</div><div class="font-weight-bold">7.50</div></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3"><div>Foreign language (<span>N1</span>)</div><div class="font-weight-bold">3</div></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3"><div>Civic Education</div><div class="font-weight-bold">7.75</div></div></div>
```

What I expected after that code is:
"Math":6.40,"Literature":4.50,etc.
But this is what I really got:

```html
"Math":6.40,
"Literature":4.50,
etc.
```

Had I messed something up?

Comment: Ah, almost forgot. This code block is placed inside a controlled loop, the i variable in the range from 2 to 7.

Comment: Try just adding `/text()` in your xpath selector instead of all those replace.

Comment: Please show me code T_T I'm totally a noob, although I know what to do, I just can't make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scrapy shell

In [1]: courses = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "d-flex justify-content-between search-result-line py-3 px-3")
   ...: ]')

In [2]: for course in courses:
   ...:     data = course.xpath('.//text()').getall()
   ...:     data_str = ' '.join(data)
   ...:     print(data_str)
   ...:
Math 6.40
Literature 4.50
History 6.50
Geography 7.50
Foreign language ( N1 ) 3
Civic Education 7.75
```